# How to stop php autocompletes in the html area?

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code, settings

I have a little problem, in .php file, i write html and php, while writing html, php suggestion started working there, and i don't want that. I want php autocompletes should work only inside , and html should work in html tags only, i want them separate and in one file.
i think, to post code here for this problem, is not necessary.

this is the video of my problem, if you are unable to understand from the statement
https://youtu.be/FIZvV3zPhOo

Comment: Im not sure how on topic this is for SO, might be a better fit on a vs forum. If you're up for changing IDEs PHP Storm is great and has much better autocomplete functionality IMHO.

Comment: maybe best to share some code though...